# Allowed lateness flink viz watermarking

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

What is the advantage of using of allowed lateness in Apache Flink?
Eg: Why not use watermarking(out of order 10units) instead of watermarking(out of order 5units)+allowed lateness(5units)?

Answer (score 0):

Allowed lateness is a concept in the windowing API -- it's not a general purpose construct.

In the case of watermarking + allowed lateness, the advantage is that the window will will be triggered and produce some (initial) results as soon as the watermark reaches the window end time. Hence, less delay before the window produces some results, with the possibility of updated results as late events arrive -- vs -- wait longer, and get a single result.

Choose whichever makes more sense for your use case. For example, some folks have rather short watermarking delays (measured in seconds), with an allowed lateness measured in tens of minutes. They wouldn't be happy if they always had to wait 30 or 60 minutes (for example) to get any results.